# UserApi is not a constructor NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, error-handling, next.js

I'm writing an app using autogenerated openapi code and when I run `yarn dev` this issue appears in the browser:

```js
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: _fitlify_io_schema__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.UserApi is not a constructor
```

I don't get any error in the editor and after building and starting the app with `yarn start`, only when trying to run it in the dev mode. Here's the code:

```js
import { UserApi } from "@fitlify-io/schema";
import { baseConfiguration } from "./base";

const userAPI = new UserApi(baseConfiguration);

export default userAPI;
```

Comment: That's because `UserApi ` is not a constructor. Did you try to log the `UserApi `?

Comment: Yes, it's an interface that extends `BaseAPI` which is a constructor. The weird thing is that other interface that are generated the same way eg. `PingApi` are completely the same, and they work properly.

Comment: That's the `BaseApi`:
```typescript
export declare class BaseAPI {
    protected configuration: Configuration;
    private middleware;
    constructor(configuration?: Configuration);
    withMiddleware<T extends BaseAPI>(this: T, ...middlewares: Middleware[]): T;
    ...
```

Comment: Please use `debugger` and show what's really in this object, not the type declaration. Type declaration and the actual object doesn't have to match.

Comment: That's what the `userAPI` variable looks like:
```typescript
UserApi {
  configuration: Configuration {
    configuration: { basePath: 'http://localhost:8080/v1', accessToken: undefined }
  },
  fetchApi: [Function (anonymous)],
  middleware: []
}
```